# AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and option AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers

Tags: ios, audio

I'm trying to use the new notification call in IOS 8.0 `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` so that I can play/pause my iPad app music accordingly when other background audio  (like the system music player) playing stops/starts (sound effects will continue and mix with either app or background music). I receive the notifications correctly when I'm not playing any music. However, while I am using an `AVAudioPlayer` to actually play my app music, the notification isn't ever called (I'm testing by starting and stopping system music with the remote on my earbuds).

If I switch to use audio session category `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` it behaves properly and sends the notification, but I need to use category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` as I'm recording during the app as well.

I realize that `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` is non-mixable by default and one wouldn't expect it to behave like `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`, but I am am setting category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`  `withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`, so that my play/record audio session should be mixable just like `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`. I would expect `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` to work in this case.

I'm wondering if anyone has been successful in getting `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` to work during app `AVAudioPlayer` play using 
`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` + `withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`

Thank you! I hope this question is specific enough, I'm new to posting on StackOverflow.

**Edit:** adding some code samples (although I know this code does work, and results only vary with audio session category/options).

---

This is called in a audio init from app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
to set up the notification on background (e.g. system player) audio status change:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(handleOtherAudioStatusChanged:)
    name:AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification
    object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

---

This is the notification callback

```
-(void)handleOtherAudioStatusChanged:(id)notification {
#if DEBUG_MODE
    NSLog(@"handleOtherAudioStatusChanged notification");
#endif
    NSNotification *n = (NSNotification *)notification;
    NSDictionary *interuptionDict = n.userInfo;

    if(interuptionDict && (n.name == AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification)) {

        // Get the AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey enum from the dictionary
        NSInteger hintType = [[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeKey] integerValue];

        // Decide what to do based on interruption type...
        switch(hintType) {

            case(AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeBegin): {
             // OTHER AUDIO STARTED
               // The system is indicating that another application's primary audio has started
#if DEBUG_MODE
                NSLog(@"In handleOtherAudioStatusChanged, other background audio started, stop game music if enabled/playing");
#endif
                // TEST AND STOP GAME MUSIC IF NEEDED                  
                break;
            } // end case

             case(AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeEnd): {
             // OTHER AUDIO STOPPED
             // The system is indicating that another application's primary audio has stopped

#if DEBUG_MODE
                NSLog(@"In handleOtherAudioStatusChanged, other background audio stopped, play game music if enabled/during game");
#endif
                // TEST AND START GAME MUSIC IF NEEDED
                break;
            }// end case
        } // end switch
    }      
}
```

---

This audio session category works all the time, while my app is playing music or not:

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
                        error:&setCategoryError];
```

This ONLY works when my app is NOT playing music. With the
withOptions override, this was supposed to be mixable like AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, so I was surprised:

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord    
                    withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                            error:&setCategoryError];
```

I tried this one too just for a test and again it ONLY works when my app is NOT playing music. But it's mixable too with this override option...

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                            error:&setCategoryError];
```

I am doing audio session setCategory/setMode/setActive in:

1. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (audio init)
2. `didBecomeActive`
3. audio interrupt method (END only)
4. and I'm testing to see if/where I need to do setActive again after a BEGIN interrupt if a matching END doesn't happen (But my test cases are showing the notification fail even when there are no audio interrupts happening).

My app music plays with a `AVAudioPlayer` appMusicPlayer;

```
self.appMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = AFCAudioLoopForever;
[self.appMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.appMusicPlayer play];
```

I have other `AVAudioPlayer`s for other very brief sound effects, and a few tests show that playing them also interferes with the `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` when in the categories/options I mentioned earlier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Bujutsu I don't see why anything more is needed. I understand the question perfectly.

Comment: Matt for me it's OK too now.

Comment: More information on this new notification in IOS 8.0: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1882/_index.html)

Comment: They say "For example, a game app
using AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient may use this property to decide to mute its soundtrack while leaving its sound effects unmuted." However, it doesn't say one HAS to use AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient. I thought it was more about mixable categories.